# Update timer UI and location information in one thread?

Tags: android, android-location

I'm new to android. I'm trying to make an application in which the user starts the timer. The timer stops when the user moves out of an area. So, I'm updating the timer UI every second(at least when it is visible) AND  updating the location. Can all this be done in one thread since I'm guessing updating the location will not be instantaneous? Putting it in the same thread as the timer will delay the timer period.
So can(should?) both be done in one thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. No it should not. If you separate it into different threads you can orchestrate things much better and react to problems separately in each thread and at the same time have it decoupled from the ui.